# Декоратор, который возвращает измененную функцию

Tags: python, exec, декоратор

У меня стоит задача автоматически модифицировать функцию, заменяя в ней некоторые конструкции на другие. После модификации ее в декораторе я вызываю exec() этой функции. При выходе из декоратора я возвращаю эту новую функцию, однако питон ругается, мол 'not defined'.

Я написал код для примера. Вот так не работает:

```py
def decorator(func):

    exec("""def new_func():
    return 'yeah'""")

    return new_func

@decorator
def some_func():
    return 'no way'

print(some_func())

# NameError: name 'new_func' is not defined
```

А вот так, например, работает.

```py
exec("""def new_func():
    return 'yeah'""")

print(new_func())

# yeah
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы функция, создаваемая в декораторе, не выдавала 'not defined'. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

```
def decorator(func):

    exec("""def new_func():
    return 'yeah'""")

    return locals()['new_func']  # Сделайте так

@decorator
def some_func():
    return 'no way'

print(some_func())
```

Но вообще, такая магия с генерацией кода в рантайме - это скользкий путь. По возможности, следует использовать более естественные средства языка.

Comment: Не так важен код, который упомянут в ответе, сколько текст под ним. Хочу обратить самое пристальное внимание на него. Использование `exec` и `eval` не полезно ни для обучения, ни для работы, потому что это запутывает логику исполнения кода, затрудняет отладку, а поддержку превращает в АД. Использование такой магии должно быть обдуманно и сопровождаться тщательным исследованием. Ведь все можно реализовать ОЧЕНЬ МНОГИМИ разными способами и не все они одинаково хороши.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Исходя из вышесказанного, подскажите пожалуйста, какой лучше выбрать способ для решения такой задачи? Например, нужно, чтобы декоратор возвращал измененную функцию:\ заменить некоторые конструкции на другие. Вот пример: нужно достать из докстринг код и вернуть функцию с такой логикой, но с замененными конструкциями switch на if.   `@support_switch
def my_function_with_switch(a: int, b: int, c: int):
 """
 switch a:
  case b:
   return True
  case c:
   return False
 """ `